# UPDATED:[MySQL won't update in Where condition PHP]

Tags: php, mysql

I just updated this question.
I can't seem to update my database whenever I am putting variable $ecode on my WHERE condition. But when I echo this variable it always echoes its right value.

```
<?php
    require 'sqlicon.php';
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $ecode= $_GET['ecode'];
    echo"".$ecode;
    $result=$db->query("UPDATE offset_form SET Approved='".$q."' WHERE Employee_Code='".$ecode."'");
?>
```

this is the content of sqlicon.php:

```
<?php
    $db=new mysqli('localhost','root','',dbuser'); //localhost,username,password, dbname
?>
```

This is where I am getting the date for $q and $ecode: Sorry if it haven't been in mysqli yet.

testingjava.php:

```
<html>
<title> Offset Requests </title>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="up.css"/></head>
<script>
    function Approval() {
        var name;
        name=document.getElementById('ename').textContent;
        if(document.form1.approval[0].checked   true) { 
            alert(name);
            window.location.href = "sqli.php?q=Yes"  + "&ecode=" + name;
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="testingjava.php"> 
    <?php
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!$conn)
            echo ("Could not connect");

        mysql_select_db("dbuser",$conn);
        $query=mysql_query("Select * from offset_form where Approved=''");
        while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $ecode=$fetch['Employee_Code'];
            //$_SESSION['ecode']=$ecode;
            $ename=$fetch['Employee_Name'];
            $epos=$fetch['Employee_Position'];
            $edpt=$fetch['Employee_Department'];
            $dleave=$fetch['Date_Leave'];
            $dreturn=$fetch['Date_Return'];
            $reason=$fetch['Offset_Reason'];

            echo "".$ecode ."".$ename." ".$epos." ".$edpt." ".$dleave." ".$dreturn." ".$reason;
            echo "<input type='radio' name='approval' onChange='Approval()'>Yes";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='approval'>No";
            echo "<input type='text' name='remarks' size='30'>";
            echo"<hr id='br'></hr>";
            echo"<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='send' onClick='Approval()'>";
        }
    ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am only testing to manipulate my database when I triggered a radio button.

Comment: echo `$sql` what does it return ?

Comment: from where you are getting the value of "ecode" ??? is  there any other php??

Comment: What are the results of var_dump($sql)?
What do $ecode and $q contain?
mysql_query is deprecated, please use mysqli or pdo instead. Also be aware that you are extremely vulnerable for a mysql injection with that code.

Comment: Please, please, please, please... how long will people continue to use the `mysql_*` extension? _It's been deprecated!!!_ switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Dont use the mysql_* functions and protect your code against SQL injection...

Comment: On a secondary note, `session_start();` should be called before sending any HTML to the browser i.e. you should call it before any of your HTML tags.

Comment: yes $ecode is from another php @PrabhakarManthena

Comment: From the updated code you have posted I don't see how things are working as you expect. Your JavaScript looks broken to me because `document.getElementById('ename')` doesn't seem to exist, unless the element is echoed out from the database? If you could run a `var_dump($ecode);` in `sqli.php` instead of `echo"".$ecode;` and put what output you get into your question it would help.

Answer (score 3):

1) you should be using  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[]) or someone with inject a mysql command into you system like DROP TABLE which will be the end of your database.

2)secondly I would move over to using PHP PDO it is more secure and it is faster (by a long way).

3) change your scond to last line from

```
mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

to

```
mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error()." _____is the string correct? ".$sql);
```

then is should echo out any errors, if you post the echoed error we can probably fix it

having looked at it I am guessing the problem is you have missed the .. around the $q, so the $sql contains the string "$q" rather than the string assigned to the variable $q

try this

```
$sql="update offset_form set Approved ='".$q."' where Employee_Code='".$ecode."'");
```

Comment: thanks mark, I tried to put your corrections, but mysql doesn't echo any errors. it seems fine. Becaause whenever I tried to INSERT a value on my database using the $ecode variable, mysql reads it fine and put its value on my table. But whenever I tried to put that $ecode variable on my WHERE condition, my databse can't seem to read it right anymore.

Comment: can you print out the value of $ecode, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: did you get it fixed in the end?

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
     $sql=("update offset_form set Approved ='".$q."' where Employee_Code='".$ecode."'");
```

always try to echo your query and see what's going wrong with your query..

Answer (score 0):

if password is set to your dbms the provide the third param passwrod

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","<passwrod>");
```

or you can leave it blank if passwrod is not set.
and try this

```
$sql="update offset_form set Approved =$q where Employee_Code=$ecode";
```

or

```
$sql="update offset_form set Approved ='".$q."' where Employee_Code='".$ecode."'";
```

note: double quotes will parse the php variable , 
most probably there is problem in the manner of quotes you are using.

Comment: if $q is a string that wont work with out the ' ' around the variables

Comment: thanks @uvais but the code still won't work. But whenever I put my $ecode to this line:
> $sql = "INSERT INTO offset_form (Approved) VALUES        ('".$ecode."')";

it works fine. mysql perfectly reads it and store it to my table

Answer (score 0):

#### are you should your query is what you want?

One thing that is confusing is the fact that you have this commented out:

```
"INSERT INTO offset_form (Approved) VALUES ('".$ecode."')"
```

And then you have this as your update:

```
"UPDATE offset_form SET Approved = '$q' WHERE Employee_Code = '".$ecode."'"
```

The values you are using don't tally together. Surely you should have:

```
"UPDATE offset_form SET Approved = '$q' where Approved = '".$ecode."'"
```

This is because you are inserting `$ecode` into the column `Approved`, but then searching for `$ecode` in another column called `Employee_Code`. Perhaps you need to modify your insert statement instead? Either that or `$ecode` could be just representing two different values at different times?

#### quotes

The only way switching quotes will make a difference is if your embedded values contain quotes themselves. In which case using the correct [escape](http://uk.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) function will sort the problem. So you are free to use either:

```
"UPDATE offset_form SET Approved = '$q' where Approved='$ecode'"
```

or:

```
"UPDATE offset_form SET Approved = '".$q."' where Approved = '".$ecode."'"
```

or:

```
'UPDATE offset_form SET Approved = "'.$q.'" where Approved = "'.$ecode.'"'
```

but not:

```
'UPDATE offset_form SET Approved = "$q" where Approved = "$ecode"'
```

either of the first three should not make a difference.

#### further things to do

**backticks**

As a rule I always write my queries escaping table and column names using backticks, just to make sure I'm not accidentally using a reserved word:

```
"UPDATE `offset_form` SET `Approved`='$q' WHERE `Employee_Code`='".$ecode."'"
```

**double check your dataset**

Make certain that the same query you are trying to run in PHP, works inside your dbms. This involves echoing the query out in PHP and then executing it via PHPMyAdmin, Navicat, or whatever you use to access your database outside of coding. For example, a query with hard-coded values, if this doesn't work you have a logic problem in your query or database design that has nothing to do with PHP:

```
"UPDATE offset_form SET Approved='13' WHERE Employee_Code='12'"
```

**check your white space**

Sometimes queries that seem they should be working are having problems because your column values contain accidental invisible white space. If so, they would only be selectable using something like:

```
"UPDATE offset_form SET Approved='$q' WHERE Employee_Code LIKE '%".$ecode."%'"
```

**check user privileges**

Make certain your MySQL user has the ability to perform the type of query you are attempting, this means allowing SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE queries.

#### *disclaimer*

*As others have already stated, you should upgrade to non deprecated database access methods. If not, you should at least be using `mysql_real_escape_string` to better protect against malicious intent.*

Comment: Thank you for your response, the I used that commented line to check if the variable $ecode is being read by the database, and it actually send the right data. But whenever i try to put the $ecode variable on my WHERE condition, mysql can't seem to find it from my database.

Comment: @user3060463 ~ in that case can you `var_dump` the value your are using for `$ecode` and put the output in your question. That will help others diagnose what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug the value of $q and try to run this code:

```
session_start();
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $ecode=$_GET['ecode'];
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$conn)
        echo ("Could not connect");

    mysql_select_db("asiantech",$conn);
    echo"".$ecode;
    echo"<br>".$q;
    $sql="update offset_form set Approved ='".mysql_real_escape_string($q)."' where Employee_Code='".$ecode."'";
    //$sql = "INSERT INTO offset_form (Approved) VALUES ('".$ecode."')";
    mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

Comment: @user3060463 please check I have updated the answer.